# How many hours does it take to get a youth level soccer coach license in Germany?

Tags: football, coaching

I am having trouble finding out how much training and the time commitment needed to get a youth level soccer coaching license in Germany. Do they even have such a thing? What is the time commitment? From what organization/authority? The only info I can find is on professional coaching licenses.

Comment: If you're having plans on living there (near the Munich Airport....?), I would ask the local soccer people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the C-license (lowest license):

„Trainer C – Leistungsfußball“/„Trainer B“ /"1. Lizenzstufe"

120 Learning units plus 20 units testing,
(including 80 learning units based knowledge, 40 learning units profiling)

1 unit = 45min

source: [DFB C-Trainer ALLGEMEINE VORAUSSETZUNGEN](http://www.dfb.de/sportliche-strukturen/trainerausbildung/c-trainer/)